How do I torify Firefox at about:config?
The following setting used to work for many years:
network.proxy.socks 127.0.0.1   
network.proxy.socks_port    9050    
network.proxy.socks_remote_dns  true    

Not anymore. Firefox does not access any onion website with this setting and
access clearnet with my public IP.
How do I torify Firefox?

You need to revise the whole network settings tab, looks like you have some extra settings involved. Also - for Firefox and darknets like Tor, I2P and many other stuff - use FoxyProxy add-on , it has very hand pattern-based request routing
